# identify() functionality with Shiny in R Programming

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to allow the user to select points on a Shiny plot to see their value, similar to the identify() function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, fairly easy too. 
Shiny plots all listen to events like X$click, x$doubleClick and invoke a call back function , with the co-ordinates.

```
xyclick <- function(e){
e$x 
e$y
//This will give you the index of whatever you were plotting
}
```

This is simple with scatter plots, if you do bar plots and other graphs, there may be some processing you have do to covert the co-ordinates to indices that you can use. 
Check out:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html